# How to customize timestamp in pattern formatter of jboss logging

Tags: java, logging, jboss, timestamp, customization

I want to change the format of timestamp in the logs generated by pattern formatter in my java `standalone.xml` file.
The current format is `"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssZZZ}"` which generates timestamp like `"2021-02-02T19:39:01.01+0530"` but my required timestamp is `"2021-02-02T19:39:01.01+05:30"`. I tried adding colon ":" in the format like `"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ss:ZZZ}"` but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the logging subsystem. The `pattern-formatte` uses the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for formatting the time stamp. In CLI you'd do the following assuming you're using the default configuration.

```
/subsystem=logging/pattern-formatter=PATTERN:write-attribute(name=pattern, value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssXXX} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n")
```

The `XXX` is the time zone in the format you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this.

```
String fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssZZZZZ";
String ldt = ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmt));
System.out.println(ldt);
```

Prints

```
2021-02-02T11:08:06.06-05:00
```

Comment: It is possible to do this in standalone.xml file becauce currently i'm directly getting the timestamp  like <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="{&quot;EntryDate&quot;:&quot;%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssZZZ}&quot;,&quot;level&quot;}%n"/>
            </formatter>       So is it possible to get the desired output just by changing the standalone.xml file

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know.  Are there any global environment variables one could set?

Comment: Umm, according to your approach I guess I can make it work by taking the value from the java code using MDC. I guess that will work